# Change value component content in controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a string that I want to call and manipulate from multiple controllers. I read up on [different types of components](http://demisx.github.io/angularjs/2014/09/14/angular-what-goes-where.html) and thought a value component would be appropriate since it only has to store a string and no logic.

With the following code, I can call the value component but how can I manipulate it so that it gets updated in all controllers:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.value('alertInfo', undefined)

.controller('Controller1', [
  'alertInfo',
  function(alertInfo) {
    alertInfo = "Some value from Controller1"
  }
])

.controller('Controller2', [
  'alertInfo',
  function(alertInfo) {
    alertInfo = "Some value from Controller2"
  }
]);
```

Comment: You can use a service to hold the value and inject it to the controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, not this way. Angular service recipes are singletons. So once you set it you cannot really update it. Instead you may want to use the object reference and update a property.

i.e example:-

```
 .value('alertInfo', {}) //Set it as an object, or object with a property with default value
```

and

```
.controller('Controller1', ['alertInfo', function(alertInfo) {
    alertInfo.value = "Some value from Controller1"; //<-- Update a property on the value object.
  }
])

.controller('Controller2', ['alertInfo', function(alertInfo) {
    alertInfo.value = "Some value from Controller2"
  }
]);
```

But ideally you could just create a service if you are planning to perform an action on the data which would be more appropriate.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.value('alertInfo', {})

.controller('Controller1', [
  'alertInfo',
  function(alertInfo) {
    alertInfo.value = "Some value from Controller1";
    this.getValue = function() {
      return alertInfo.value;
    }
    this.update = function() {
      alertInfo.value = "Updated from Controller1";
    }
  }
])

.controller('Controller2', [
  'alertInfo',
  function(alertInfo) {
    alertInfo.value = "Some value from Controller2";
    this.getValue = function() {
      return alertInfo.value;
    }
    this.update = function() {
      alertInfo.value = "Updated from Controller2";
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Controller1 as ctrl1">{{ctrl1.getValue()}}
    <button ng-click="ctrl1.update()">Update</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="Controller2 as ctrl2">{{ctrl2.getValue()}}
    <button ng-click="ctrl2.update()">Update</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I only use the component to store notification messages set by different controllers, there's no logic attached to it. Would you recommend a service for that?

Comment: @migu Probably my opinion but i have never see `value` recipe is of any use to me till now :). I would just create a messageService and update via update method and get via get method on the service rather than exposing the object as is.

Comment: I see. What's the benefit of wrapping it in a getter / setter method?

Comment: @migu i meant you expose it as an api rather than modifying the underlying object directly.